# Thumbnail for music files in android

Tags: android

I want to get thumbnail for music files from there path or id .How can i achieve this?. I know that there is a default directory in android with thumbnails of all music files ,is there a way to find the thumbnail of a music file from there using either file path or id?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily parse mp3 files, in you read The MP3 Tag Standard: http://id3.org/ **<-- this is the best way**

Other good way is obtain album/artist name and title, then ask some third-party service for cover. For example, lastfm have good API.

You also can take look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that worked for me

```
 public  Bitmap coverpicture(String path) {

        MediaMetadataRetriever mr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        mr.setDataSource(path);

        byte[] byte1 = mr.getEmbeddedPicture();
        mr.release();
    if(byte1 != null)
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte1, 0, byte1.length);
    else
        return  null;

}
```